# How to use pre trained word2vec model?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, keras

Where can I find a reliable `word2vec` model trained on some English articles?

I need a `word2vec` black box, where I, for example, can pass a sentence as array:
`["London", "is", "the", "capital", "of", "Great", "Britain"]`

and receive:
`[some_vector_of_floats1, some_vector_of_floats2, some_vector_of_floats3, some_vector_of_floats4, some_vector_of_floats5, some_vector_of_floats6, some_vector_of_floats7]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Python, you can use [Gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim)

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('path-to-vectors.txt', binary=False)
# if you vector file is in binary format, change to binary=True
sentence = ["London", "is", "the", "capital", "of", "Great", "Britain"]
vectors = [model[w] for w in sentence]
```

[These vectors](https://github.com/alexandres/lexvec#pre-trained-vectors) should give you better performance than the pre-trained ones you'd get with word2vec.

Comment: thank you very much. it probably works, but I receive the error KeyError: 'of'

Comment: That means of is not in your model's vocabulary. Which vectors are you using?

Comment: GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin

Comment: I use that model in node-word2vec and it works there with sentence about London

Comment: Did you change binary=True to binary=False as noted? The pre-trained Google vectors are in binary format.

Comment: I've set binary to True. with binary=False it throws UnicodeDecodeError error

Comment: Can you try these ( http://nlpserver2.inf.ufrgs.br/alexandres/vectors/lexvec.enwiki%2bnewscrawl.300d.W.pos.vectors.gz ) and set binary=False ?

Comment: it throws: KeyError: 'London'. maybe you know some good trained model, which knows all words?

Comment: London is a fairly common word but most pre-trained embeddings remove casing. Try using vectors = [model[w.lower()] for w in sentence]. It will use the word "london" instead of "London", and it should work as expected. If you insist on casing, try http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/wordvecs/glove.840B.300d.zip , but beware the size of these vectors. Loading the model will use a lot of memory.

Comment: one more question) what if I need to represent "great britain" as single token?

Comment: Can you create another question dedicated to this? It is an interesting question in it of its own.

Comment: yes. I've created: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267215/how-to-use-multiple-words-token-with-gensim-word2vec

Answer (score 1):

I slightly modified the code - for my purposes

```
vocab = model.vocab.keys()
sentence = ["London", "is", "the", "capital", "of", "Great", "Britain"]
vectors=[]
for w in sentence:
    if w in vocab:
        vectors.append(model[w])
    else:
        print("Word {} not in vocab".format(w))
        vectors.append([0])
```

You could also use a try/catch - your call.